# How to run a task only once during entire Ansible Playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a Ansible playbook which does multiple things as below -

1. Download artifacts fron nexus into local server (Ansible Master).
2. Copy those artifacts onto multiple remote machines let's say server1/2/3 etc..

And I have used roles in my playbook and the role (repodownload) which downloads the artifacts I want to run it only once because why would i want to download the same thing again. I have tried to use run_once: true but i guess that won't work because that only works for one playbook run but my playbook is running multiple times for multiple hosts.

`---
- name: Deploy my Application to tomcat nodes
  hosts: '{{ target_env }}'
  serial: 1
  roles:
    - role: repodownload
      tags:
        - repodownload
    - role: copyrepo
      tags:
        - copyrepo
    - role: stoptomcat
      tags:
        - stoptomcat
    - role: deploy
      tags:
        - deploy`

Here target_env is being passed from the command line and it's the remote host group.
Any help is appreciated.

Below is the code from main.yml from repodownload role -

`- connection: local
   name: Downloading files from Nexus to local server
   get_url: url="{{ nexus_url }}/{{item}}/{{ myvm_release_version }}/{{item}}-{{ release_ver }}.war" dest={{ local_server_location }}
   with_items:
    - "{{ temps }}"`

Comment: Why do you run the role on all your hosts if you only need it for localhost ? Put it in a seperate play targeting localhost only, leave the other roles on the next play targeting your environment and your are done.

Comment: @Zeitounator I agree but I was thinking of running just one play for my entire deployment steps which includes download the files as well. Right now it is a manual step. Is there no other way?

Comment: What is the problem with having 2 plays in the same playbook ? This would contain your entire deployment steps in a single playbook that you can run at once.

Comment: @Zeitounator Ok. I will try to do that. The thing is I am using group_var and supplying my target env as a command line argument (it could be prod, preprod etc.). Inside /group_vars/ I have defined prod.yml where all the remote server variables are defined. I also need to define the local server location and other variables. Where do i define that? For Example - 

`---
 - hosts: localhost
   tasks:
     - name: Ensureing that directory exist
       file:
         path: "{{ local_server_location }}"
         state: directory`

Comment: in `vars` in your localhost play ?

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks a lot for your quick responses. I was able to make it work using tags. I defined a file in group_vars called localhost.yml and also defined the same entry in my inventory like `[localhost]10.10.10.10`. So when running he playbook, it is using that file and picking up the variables from there.

Might not be the best solution but I am still very new to Ansible so trying out different options.
Many thanks again and I might post some more questions in the coming days :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a really simple one that I battled with too.

Try this:

```yaml
- connection: local
   name: Downloading files from Nexus to local server
   get_url:
     url:  "{{ nexus_url }}/{{item}}/{{ myvm_release_version }}/{{item}}-{{ release_ver }}.war"
     dest: "{{ local_server_location }}"
   with_items:
    - "{{ temps }}"
   run_once: true
```

Just something else, unrelated to your main question;

When you run a module that has really long args, like in your example above, rather break the params into their own lines nested under the module. It makes for easier reading, and it makes it easier to spot any potential typos or syntax errors early.

Answer (score 0):

Okay extending from your converstation with [Zeitounator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9401096/zeitounator). The following workaround will work without changing your vars files. Just remember that this is a workaround, might not be the most efficient way to do the job.

```
---
- name: Download my repo to localhost
  # Executes only for first host in target_env and has visibility to group vars of target_env
  hosts: '{{ target_env }}[0]'
  serial: 1
  roles:
    - role: repodownload
      tags:
        - repodownload

- name: Deploy my Application to tomcat nodes
  # Executes for all hosts in target_env
  hosts: '{{ target_env }}'
  serial: 1
  roles:
    - role: copyrepo
      tags:
        - copyrepo
    - role: stoptomcat
      tags:
        - stoptomcat
    - role: deploy
      tags:
        - deploy
```